# How can get the href value from a inside TD

Tags: jquery, html

I still tried to get the href link from the anchor isnide my TD but i'm not able for to do it.

Always i got the undefined as a result.

i expect the return: /Admin/Log/Profile/

```js
console.log($(".clickable-row").find("a").attr("href"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="userListResult">
      <td class="clickable-row"><a href="/Admin/Log/Profile/">abc</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you putting it inside $(document).ready ?

Comment: Yes, i did, everthing work on Jquery, just this part i got problems

Comment: Do you have a `<table>` element ? Without it the html shown is invalid and browsers produce unpredictable results with invalid markup. Otherwise when there is a table the code shown works fine

Comment: Yes, i have.
I just put a part of code for make a simple fpr try to help me

Comment: Works fine here when in a table https://jsfiddle.net/8zbsvc5t/

Comment: In your Jsfiddle it did the redirect,, but u can get the value from href.
Try use a valid url: https://jsfiddle.net/8zbsvc5t/

Comment: Not understanding what you mean. Try editing question with more specific details. Note I moved your code into an editable and runnable snippet also so you can see the results here in this page.

Comment: Yes, and when i ran on snippet it's work, but i dont know whats happend here :(

Comment: How can i give to u the credit for the correct answer? @charlietfl

Comment: I didn't really answer anything other than to say the code works fine...which isn't a valid answer since the problem you have is unknown